# How to update the google map if the map canvas of it changed its dimenstions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map inside of a div which gets changed, its parent div can get an additional class which changes its dimensions. This changes causes the google map not to get updated, it resist in the previous dimensions. How can I refresh the google map?

I tried to recreate the google map again but it seems to keep the other previously created google maps there as well. This causes sometimes strange behavior (the old map is on the top of the new). Can a google map be released?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the [google.maps.Map class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) reference, I think you're looking for the `resize` event:

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Comment: This solution sounds great. probably I can just as well set an event listener for this. Actually the map I need has to have one max. one marker which should be centered after the resize.

Comment: no, when I try to catch the event, it does trigger the listener before doing the resize. An after resize event would be useful too..

Answer (score 0):

While re-sizing the existing map would be more elegant, as a workaround you can empty the container div before re-creating the map, e.g. `while (div.firstChild) div.removeChild(div.firstChild)` or `$(div).empty()`.