# Javascript accordion feature causes partial displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show 2 different maps in accordion(JavaScript Enabled). The main purpose of doing this was to show users an accordion so that users can click on one another to see rather than seeing two big `<div>` otherwise.

I have done this code (http://jsbin.com/ibanum/1/edit), but the problem is that the second map does appear partially not fully as map1. How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here lies the answer. You should refresh the div on click. So here goes the final JavaScript. But before going there you may have a look at http://jsbin.com/ibanum/20/edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1391265, 11.580186300000037);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: fenway,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP


    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), mapOptions);

    $('#accordion').accordion();
    $('h3').click(function () {

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

});
```

Now the line

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

resizes the map as there is a click event on the `<h3>` tag. Hope this sample is clear

Comment: Yeah, after resizing, it will be displayed. But, not a solution of the problem.

Comment: @JohnSmith I am looking into it. Did you do this locally. Is there too the same Problem?

Comment: Yes, I did. The same problem exists.

Comment: @JohnSmith Hope this solution works at your end. Kinda refresh at the div. Sorry my network is a bit slow and JSBin really becomes slower!! :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh your map container when switching between accordion section by using :

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

See the related topic : [how-to-update-the-google-map-if-the-map-canvas-of-it-changed-its-dimenstions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226497/how-to-update-the-google-map-if-the-map-canvas-of-it-changed-its-dimenstions)

Comment: Its not about dimensions. Its about the event that is triggered and when the map suddenly pops up from a div that was hidden. It happens.

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago, its because that you second map canvas is already loaded but not shown. By doing this, when the second map canvas will be displayed, the resize event, will display a clean map canvas. There is not refresh option event on Google Maps API.